# ReflectionUtils how to replace deprecated methods?

Tags: java, spring, reflection

Many methods in the `org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils` package have been deprecated, but there is no hint which methods should be used as a replacement. How are the following methods to be replaced properly?

```
org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible();
org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.isAccessible();
```

My goal is to get all field names and save them into a `Map`. So far the following code worked, but how can I replace the deprecated methods?

```
ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(object.getClass(), field -> {
            if (!field.isAccessible()) ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
            map.put(field.getName(), ReflectionUtils.getField(field, object));
        });
```

Comment: It is deprecated because it is deprecated in the JVM (and probably will be removed and disallowed). This will probably already get you into issues with a JPMS based (Module-Path instead of ClassPath) based system as you are severely restricted in what you can see and do with reflection. (Which is also why it is deprecated and going to be removed from the JDK).

Comment: I see, but how could I then get a list of fields accessible, as an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of module system accessible checks and changes uses now new methods, to make something accessible you should look at `trySetAccessible`:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#trySetAccessible()
it returns true/false value instead of exception.

And to check for access use `canAccess(object)`:

> object - an instance object of the declaring class of this reflected object if it is an instance method or field

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#canAccess(java.lang.Object)

Comment: So I would leave out the check if the field is accessible at all, and just execute `trySetAccessible()` instead of makeAccessible?

Comment: yep, it should work fine too. (unless that class is from other module that does not want to allow reflective access on it)